# Get string from CSV/JSON using PHP

Tags: php, json

I have **data.json** like this :

```
{
    "201206": "6664 SPRINT SPECTRUM, L.P.",
    "201207": "6391 CELLCO PARTNERSHIP DBA VERIZON WIRELESS - NJ",
    "201208": "4036 NEW CINGULAR WIRELESS PCS, LLC - DC",
    "201209": "9206 VERIZON NEW JERSEY, INC.",
    "201210": "7421 AT&AMP;T - LOCAL",
    "201216": "9206 VERIZON NEW JERSEY, INC.",
    "201217": "9206 VERIZON NEW JERSEY, INC.",
    "201218": "4036 NEW CINGULAR WIRELESS PCS, LLC - DC",
    "201219": "6630 USA MOBILITY WIRELESS, INC.",
    "201220": "4036 NEW CINGULAR WIRELESS PCS, LLC - DC"
}
```

and I have **data.txt** like this:

```
201206
201207
201208
201209
```

and I want to validate my `data.txt` and get output like this :

```
201206@6664 SPRINT SPECTRUM, L.P.
201207@6391 CELLCO PARTNERSHIP DBA VERIZON WIRELESS - NJ
201208@4036 NEW CINGULAR WIRELESS PCS, LLC - DC
201209@9206 VERIZON NEW JERSEY, INC.
```

I want to get the output with a single execution. Is that possible and how?

For now, i use this methode :

GET localhost/check.php?list=201206

```
$list = $_GET['list'];
$data_json = json_decode(file_get_contents("data.json"), true);
$result = $data_json[''.$list.''];
```

then i run rollingcurl.
Maybe there is any other solutions?

Comment: Yes it's possible. Where are you stuck? What have you researched and tried? It looks like first you have to find each item in the JSON which matches an item in your data.txt. Then you combine the fields to produce the output. So actually maybe first you have to read and parse both files. We're happy to help if you can identify a specific issue, but if you break down the process like I've just done then each part is very standard and should be possible to research and find examples which you can adapt for your situation.

Comment: @ADyson for now i only can execute 1 by 1 from data text, like API. 

GET localhost/check.php?list=201206

$list = $_GET['list'];
$data_json = json_decode(file_get_contents("data.json"), true); 
$result = $data_json[''.$list.'']

Comment: That doesn't even try to read from the txt file...

Answer (score 1):

Read the text file into an array, then use your code in a loop.

```
$data_list = file("data.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINE);
$data_json = json_decode(file_get_contents("data.json"), true);
foreach ($data_list as $list) {
    if (isset($data_json[$list])) {
        echo "$list@{$data_json[$list]}<br>";
    }
}
```